# Facebook login with NextJS next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to connect my app with facebook login. currently i'm using the developer environment under meta developers account.

I have a login component which looks like below -

```
import Image from "next/image"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="grid place-items-center">
      <Image
      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Facebook_Logo.png?20170210095314" 
      width={300} 
      height={300} 
      style={{objectFit:"contain"}} 
      alt="logo"
       />
       <h1 
       className="p-5 m-5 bg-blue-500 rounded-full text-white text-center cursor-pointer" 
       onClick={signIn}>Login with Facebook</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

and here is my code from [...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
export const authOptions = {
  
  providers: [
      FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    
  ],
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

When i click on login with facebook button it throws error

[image]
Any help .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encountered the same problem below solution works for me.

I made a silly mistake. The Problem was with `NEXT_AUTH_URL`.

The url was pointing to `https://localhost:3000` which is creating the issue.

I have updated url to `http://localhost:3000`.

And everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I spent at least 2 hours on this. If someone is struggling with this issue in live/staging environment, double check on Facebook Developer platform whether you have put your URLs not only in the App -> Domains list, but also under "valid OAuth redirect URL".

Click on "use cases" -> Facebook login -> click on "Review"
Then go to settings and then add your URL + /api/auth/callback/facebook

Comment: Which field did you save this in Facebook app settings?

Comment: I tried putting this in "valid OAuth redirect URL", `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/facebook` but got the following prompt `http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here.` and facebook won't allow me to save

Comment: @D.Rattansingh did you figure it out?

Comment: @magnus no. It's not accepting http:localhost, I tried the vercel URL but still no luck. I got next-auth working with google but not for facebook

Comment: @D.Rattansingh same here